# square summable maesurable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a measurable space and $I$ be a uncountable set.

Let $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $\{g_i\}_{i\in I}$ be two family of measurable unctions on $\Omega$. Assume that for any $x\in \Omega$, both $\{f_i(x)\}$ and $\{g_i(x)\}$
are in the Hilbert space $\ell^2(I)$.

Question: Is the mapping  $h(x)=\sum f_i(x)g_i(x)$ a measurable function as well?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand: How are $f$ and $g$ related to $f_i$ and $g_i$?

Comment: Do you mean $fg(x)=\sum\limits_{i\in I} f_i(x)g_i(x)$?

Comment: Oh sorry. I now correct the question. Actually, I feel it is not measurable in general !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider $\Bbb R$ with  the Lebesgue measurable sigma-algebra. Let $I=\Bbb R$. Let $E$ be a non-measurable subset of $\Bbb R$. If $i\in\Bbb R\setminus E$ define $f_i(x)=g_i(x)=0$ for all $x$. If $i\in E$ define $f_i(x)=g_i(x)=1$ for $x=i$ and $f_i(x)=g_i(x)=0$ for $x\ne i$. Then $\sum_i f_ig_i$ is the characteristic function of $E$.